# IntelliJ: cannot resolve symbol "setVisible"

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

So I just started using IntelliJ and already encountered a problem, it involves IntelliJ and JFrame. I was just starting my code then I noticed the red text after compiling the error message said that the .setVisible cannot be resolved, how do I fix this? the code so far is this...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test_001 {
    JFrame frameOne = new JFrame("Test");
    frameOne.setVisible(true);
}//Class
```

My project uses the SDK java.version 1.8.0.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it in a main function:

```
public class Test_001 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frameOne = new JFrame("Test");
    frameOne.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: oh wow, didn't notice I made an obvious mistake there. Thanks for the answer.